# QT C++. Отключение warning'ов для конкретных файлов через .pro

Tags: c++, qt, warning, qmake

Здравствуйте! У нас в проекте есть директория с файлами загружаемыми через внешние ссылки svn. Редактировать эти файлы не допускается. И проблема в том что в этих файлах присутствует множество warning'ов. Файли лежат в директории /External. Можно ли игнорировать все файлы находящиеся в данной директории на предмет варнингов (при этом сохраняя warning'и для остальных файлов)? И если можно, то как? Спасибо.

Comment: Можете игнорировать варнинги всех файлов из той директории :)

Comment: А можно подробнее, как именно?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, нет. Можно только для всех файлов. Либо можно сделать проект subdirs， и в нём в дочернем проекте собирать сторонние файлы как статическую библиотеку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать флаг `-isystem` для пути, в котором происходит поиск подключаемых файлов, что бы игнорировать warning для этого пути. Для Qt это будет выглядеть так:

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem "$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/qt5" \
-isystem "$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/qt5/QtWidgets"`

Каждую отдельную директорию необходимо "заглушать" отдельно.